# Login to PHP form and then run a PHP script in Java

Tags: java, http, httpconnection

I've now realised that everything I just had up was garbage. My problem is that after I do my POST to the php login script, the response coming back doesn't contain the "key" (Set-Cookie:amember_nr=blah) that I need. Without it the main php script can't verify me and thinks I am not logged in. I've even recreated an entire GET and POST header from my browser and tried using those, but still nothing. Any ideas why this would be happening? I'm using Apache Commons HttpClient.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide the relevant code (both Java and PHP) that you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the HtmlUnit API. Handy API, even though I am only kind of using it for what it is meant for.